# Calculate the greater value between objects in different arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a `score` array containing two objects: **Liga** and **Premier**. These 2 objects are an array of a list of teams.

I was able to define the greater string when `score` was previously a single array of objects.

This is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-examples-y0y7q) i have reproduced where the comparison works fine.

This is the code calculating the higher value comparing the 2 objects.

```
const maxAverage = teams => {
  return teams.map(team => {
      return {
          team:team, 
          avg: getAverage(team)
      }
  }).reduce((a,b)=>a.avg>b.avg?a:b).team
}


<p>Stronger Team:{maxAverage([this.state.homeCity,this.state.awayCity])</p>
```

The problem now is that now `score` is an array of the 2 object as i said and i am trying to change my function in something like

```
const maxAverage = (league, teams) => {
  return teams.map(team => {
      return {
          team:team,
          avg: getAverage(league,team)
      }
  }).reduce((a,b)=>a.avg>b.avg?a:b).team
}
```

I am not able to pass to my function `maxAverage` the parameter of one of the two leagues selected and then the 2 objects ( teams ) i want to compare.

i want to do something like this:

```
<p>Stronger Team:{maxAverage([this.state.selectedLeague], this.state.selectedHomeTeam,this.state.selectedAwayTeam])}
```

This is the other [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-examples-lb22e) i have reproduced with the current situation.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: I have put my 2 codesandbox linked. See the demo links in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the signature `const maxAverage = (league, teams) => ...`, following code would match the expected arguments (not sure about the business logic though):

```
maxAverage(
  this.state.selectedLeague,
  [this.state.selectedHomeTeam, this.state.selectedAwayTeam]
)
```

Comment: It answer the questions, so i can accept it, but it looks now the Max average is not done correctly and it only look up for the big number to define the stronger team, it does not matter if it is negative or positive number

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your second demo and I think you have two choices to get the correct team selected and you can reuse your previous getAverage method for both. Either

```
  const maxAverage = (league, teams) => {
  const currentLeague = [scores][0][league]
  return teams
    .map(team => {
      return {
        team: team,
        avg: getAverage(currentLeague, team)
      };
    })
    .reduce((a, b) => (a.avg > b.avg ? a : b)).team;
};
```

alternatively you could keep the original maxAverage code and change how you implement the league value eg.

```
            <p>           
              Stronger Team:
              {maxAverage(scores[this.state.selectedLeague], [
                this.state.selectedHomeTeam,
                this.state.selectedAwayTeam
              ])}
            </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply extract team when selected, save in the state and use the same method used before?

Comment: if you can show me the code in the example to accept the answer i can see it

Answer (score 0):

What is a problem?

```
const scores = {'liga':[
  { day: "1", Barcelona: 1, Real: 3, Valencia: 0 },
  { day: "2", Barcelona: 4, Real: 6, Valencia: 3 },
  { day: "3", Barcelona: 7, Real: 7, Valencia: 3 },
  { day: "4", Barcelona: 7, Real: 8, Valencia: 6 }
], 'primier':[
  { day: "1", Barcelona: 1, Real: 3, Valencia: 0 },
  { day: "2", Barcelona: 4, Real: 6, Valencia: 3 },
  { day: "3", Barcelona: 7, Real: 7, Valencia: 3 },
  { day: "4", Barcelona: 7, Real: 8, Valencia: 6 }]};
const getAverage = (type, team) => {
  if (isNaN(scores[type][0][team])) return null;

  return scores[type].map(x => x[team]).reduce((a, c) => a + c) / scores[type].length;
};
getAverage('liga',this.state.homeCity);
```

src:
https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-examples-d9qy0